# Laravel "[b" character on version 4.1.x

Tags: laravel

Installed Laravel 4.1.30 (because I can't use 4.2 on a RHEL5 server - no PHP 5.4), all seemed to go OK, but noticed the sequence `"[B"` showing up when a user is logged into my test application.
I even see that just getting the Laravel version:

```
./artisan --version
[BLaravel Framework version 4.1.30
```

On v4.2, I'm not seeing that.

```
./artisan --version
Laravel Framework version 4.2.6
```

I *cannot* upgrade the version of Laravel on the server because of no PHP5.4 support (the server isn't mine).  Any idea what is causing the stray "[B"?  It's an issue because as I mentioned, it also shows up in my application.

e.g.
Section from a blade view:

```
@section('content')
  (here1)
  @if(Auth::check())
    (auth)
  @else
    (not-auth)
  @endif
  (here2)
```

Displays this on the site:

```
(here1) [B (auth) (here2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue at one point as well where I would get a "/" whenever I ran artisan commands etc.. it turned out I had a / before one of my opening `<?php` tags that I missed. `/<?php`. Just do a quick search/replace on the [B string in your project and hopefully you can locate the offending file.

Comment: Thanks - it was a stray [B string in my database.php file.